Debian: No GUI (after upgrading from buster to bullseye)
After upgrading my Debian stable 10 buster to 11 bullseye, which I did by the book, I got a message during the final full-upgrade that some packages couldn't be properly installed (in my case, one was linux-image-amd64 and the message was to the effect that it is 5.10.xx, which is not installed). Ok. I rebooted and ended up w/ a black screen w/ a blinking cursor on upper left. Help!

Solved as follows:

Key Alt-F1...F6 to switch to a terminal. Log in
sudo apt update, which got me an error Release is not valid yet (invalid for another XXmin YYs). After some googling, the hardware clock seemed to be the problem. date showed me that the time was indeed wrong, while cat /etc/timezone and date +"%Z %z" proved that the timezone was correct. I corrected the time w/ sudo date --set 21:53:20 and made the change permanent w/ sudo hwclock --systohc
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade (got a message that /etc/sysctl.conf on my system has been changed. The default was to Keep, but I decided it's safer to Install the maintainer's new version — see here). The upgrade told me there are some problems and suggested Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt upgrade. Got some errors again, the first of which was cpio: write error: No space left on device. Aha! df assured me of 100% / use. Finally, we're getting somewhere
sudo apt autoremove (during the last update, I'd noticed that a whole bunch of packages could be autoremoved). After this df showed me 96% /
sudo apt upgrade (finished successfully)
sudo reboot (all's fine)

Analysis
Before the release upgrade, I'd paid attention to the space requirement and conjectured that I had enough. What I hadn't foreseen was the large number of obsoleted packages that could be autoremoved. If I had autoremoved them between the final update and upgrade (as actually suggested here), all would have probably gone smoothly. Examining the partitions w/ sudo gparted told me my / is indeed very small (below 10GB), set to the minimal size as I had separate home and data partitions. However, 10GB is seemingly insufficient for Debian / even if you think you won't use many programs (as they'll accumulate over years, after which you may have to do a release upgrade, taking even more space in turn). So now I'll start working w/ gparted to expand the / to at least 15GB (this requires some stretching and moving of partitions, which in my case is luckily possible)

Congratulations on answering your own question.  These Answers are always the toughest to come up with nut provide the most satisfaction.
